# changing Persian font via script doesn't work unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, fonts, farsi

i have a strange problem to changing Persian(right to left languages) Font via script. when i got my text from webservice and aftar converting that to the correct veiw using Unity3DFarsi library,i loaded my Font where placed in Resource folder in assets through bellow code:

```
font = Resources.Load("myfont") as Font;
tempButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().font = font;
tempButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text=sample.faConvert(); //sample is my text
```

my problem is that however the font changed in unity editor to "myfont" ,it has NO effect to my text and didn't change that,bellow is shot of my scene.
pleaseee help.thanks
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSTuQ.png)

[[image: PersianTextsExample]

Comment: What's your Unity version? Also can you link the persian text that is not showing? If possible, also provide link to the font.

Comment: @Programmer it's Unity 5.6.0f3 Personal. it's not a specific Font, for example every font which the name starts with F_(...).also i updated the Q with some persian texts. noticed that it is shown but font does't affact it.

Comment: Sorry. How do you now it has no effect? What is the output supposed to look like?

Comment: I always use Persian fonts in microsoft word so i know their form

Comment: If you can do 3 things for me, I will see if I can help. 1.Edit your question and show what the current font looks like(You already did). 2.Edit your question and show what it should look like. 3.Edit your question and show the persian text you are using for the test on both images in persian. Show that text in text not in screenshot. I will try to replicate your problem and see what I can do.